# Как добавить тень CircleImageView?

Tags: android

Здравствуйте! Подскажите как можно добавить тень CircleImageView, есть ли вообще такая возможность?

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                            android:id="@+id/circlImg"
                            android:layout_width="80dp"
                            android:layout_height="80dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/kniga"
                            card_view:border_color="@color/colorPrimary"
                            app:border_width="2dp"
                            android:elevation="5dp"

                           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
                            card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                            />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вариантов [множество](https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&q=android+cicrcleimageview+shadow)

Comment: Я написал card_view:cardElevation="5dp", но тень не появилась

Comment: с чего вы взяли, что у данного виджета есть атрибут cardElevation? его нет ни в исходниках библиотеки, ни у виджета `ImageView` от которого он наследуется. Это атрибут виджета `CardView`, который никаким боком не относится к вашему виджету. Параметр elevation работает только с API21 и виджет, кроме того, должен иметь параметр background